# HASHTALBE USO DE OBJETO COMO KEY

Tags: java

este es un ejemplo simple de algo que necesito.
tengo una clase principal que llama a una clase remedio.
no s'e como usar en la clase principal el objeto remedio para recuperar la cantidad.
esto es hashtable.
cualquier aclaraci'on denme aviso proque creo que es algo tan simple que no me doy cuenta.
DEBeria poner el remedio chau y deber'ia recuperar la cantidad y en base a eso resuelvo.

```
public static void main (String [] args) {          
    Hashtable <Remedio, Integer> remedios = new Hashtable <Remedio,
      Integer>();
            Remedio remedio3 = new Remedio("chau", "flores", 13);       
    remedios.put(remedio1, 15);
    remedios.put(remedio2, 19);
    remedios.put(remedio3, remedio3.getStock());
    remedios.put(remedio4, 16);
    Scanner e = new Scanner (System.in);
    e.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    System.out.println("inges el nombre del reme");
    String xx = e.next();
    if(remedios.containsKey(remedios.toString() == xx)) {

    //System.out.println("existe " + remedio3.getNombre() +"-"+    
       remedio3.getEnfermedad());
        System.out.println("ingrese chau");
        String dd = e.next();
        if ("chau" == dd) {
            System.out.println("son iguales");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("no son iguales");
        }
    }

    Enumeration<Remedio> clavess = remedios.keys();
    while (clavess.hasMoreElements()) {
        Remedio clave = clavess.nextElement();
        System.out.println(remedios.get(clave));
    //System.out.println(remedios.get(remedio2).toString());        
    }
}

public class Remedio {
private String nombre;
private int stock;
private String enfermedad;
public Remedio (String nombr, String enfermeda, int stoc) {
    nombre = nombr;
    stock = stoc;
    enfermedad = enfermeda;
}
public String getEnfermedad()
public void setEnfermedad(String enfermedad) {
}
public String getNombre()
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public int getStock() {
}
public void setStock(int stock) {
this.stock = stock;
}   
}
```

Tuve que borrar unas lineas porque stko se queja
es un simple ejemplo para resolver algo que estoy probando.
el tema es que pones un texto de entrada que coincide con la clave y recupera la cantidad.

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso haría el siguiente código:

```
Hashtable <String, Remedio> remedios = new Hashtable <String, Remedio>();
```

Esto debido a que los `Hashtable` funcionan bajo la métodología **"clave:valor"** y por tanto la clave debe ser algo sencillo y ya el valor viene siendo lo más complejo.

Finalmente para llevar a cabo tu idea sería algo tan simple como

```
remedios.get(xx).getStock();
```

Espero te sirva.